# HQL unexpected AST node

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I am getting following error for my query in HQL

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: COUNT near line 1

My query is following

```
@Query("SELECT new com.model.CompanyInfoMapping(c.company_id, c.company_name)"
            + "FROM Company c Inner JOIN c.companyInfo ci INNER JOIN c.portfolioPrivate ppc               "
            + " WHERE (ppc.beschreibung_id ='1'  AND ppc.value = 'Yes') "
            + " OR (ppc.beschreibung_id ='2'  AND ppc.value = 'Yes')" 
            + " GROUP BY c.company_id "
            + " HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ppc.value ='Yes' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) " )
```

Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As HAVING should be a condition I should think it needs to be

```
+ " HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ppc.value ='Yes' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) > 0 " )
```